# How to show gaps with plotly scatter graphs

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, scatter-plot

i have two pandas series:

```
x=[59281.021432, 59281.063095, 59281.104768, 59283.188094, 59283.313102]
x=pd.Series(x)
y=[1.0, 2.1, 3.3, 12.1, 12.3]
y=pd.Series(y)
```

which have the same size. When i plot the graph with plotly i don't see the gaps:

```
fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(xaxis_title='MJD [days]', yaxis_title='value'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines'))
```

[image]

What i would like to see is the same graph, but with the gap without the line. Is it possible? I see that i should put a None character into the serie x between 59281.104768 and 59283.188094, but how?

i have tried this code to obtain the lower and the upper boudaries, but i do not know how to complete the  series adding None values:

```
delta = x[1] - x[0]
lowerBounds = (x+delta)[:-1]
upperBounds = (x-delta)[1:]
lowerBounds=lowerBounds.to_numpy()
upperBounds=upperBounds.to_numpy()
mask = lowerBounds<=upperBounds
upperBounds, lowerBounds = upperBounds[mask], lowerBounds[mask]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is what you're aiming to do:

[image]

If that's the case then I would organize your series in a dataframe, subset the dataframe according to a defined `gap`, and then use `add_trace` for each subset.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
x=[59281.021432, 59281.063095, 59281.104768, 59283.188094, 59283.313102]
x=pd.Series(x)
y=[1.0, 2.1, 3.3, 12.1, 12.3]
y=pd.Series(y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,
                   'y':y})

gap = 12

fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(xaxis_title='MJD [days]', yaxis_title='value'))
# fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df['y']>gap]['x'],
                         y=df[df['y']>gap]['y'], mode = 'lines',
                         line=dict(color='blue')))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df['y']<gap]['x'],
                         y=df[df['y']<gap]['y'], mode = 'lines',
                         line=dict(color='blue')))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Yes this is what i want graphically, but I don't want to separate the lines, because in principle I don't know if gap is equal 12, I could have a y series equal to [1.0, 2.1, 3.3, 2.1, 2.3]

Comment: @Andrea I think you'll have define a threshold for a gap *somehow* either way. How do you expect plotly to know *not* to draw a line between only *some* of the points in a trace?

Comment: you're right, for that reason i have done a function that normalize the trace putting a None value if the difference between two consecutive values is greater than a defined threeshold. Thank you for your clarification

Comment: @Andrea OK! If my suggestion was uesful, please consider leaving an upvote and / or mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Andrea Thank you for accepting my answer!